# Testing reducers which change multiple properties with Immutable.js

Tags: testing, redux, immutable.js

I'm attempting to migrate a React/Redux app to `Immutable.JS` and have a question about testing.

Given a reducer which does something like this:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

  case RUN_ENDED:
    return state.set('isRunning', false)
                .set('roundResult', action.data)
  default:
   return state
}
```

I would like to test that both properties have been set correctly.

My old tests would have looked like this:

```
it('should handle the RUN_ENDED action', () => {

  const action = {
    type: RUN_ENDED,
    data: {
      winnerId: 0
    }
  }

  const result = simulatorReducer(undefined, action)

  expect(result).to.deep.equal({
    isRunning: false,
    roundResult: action.data
  })

})
```

With Immutable I don't seem able to do these comparisons in quite the same way. I can explicitly check each value in `result` with `result.get('theProperty')` but this seems a bit laborious if I have 5-6 values.

Is there some way to do this with Immutable?

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-immutable-matchers

so for example:
`expect(result).toEqualImmutable(Immutable.Map({isRunning: false, ...}));`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, following their guides still gives me some errors about library usage. I'm not sure the approach would work in general though as I have some initial state which would be returned along with my changed values from the reducer, but I'd expect the `toEqualImmutable()` function in that library to check for value based equality on all the values which will leave me where I am at the moment.

Comment: just checked the source code, it is using `Immutable.is` so it is checking that the values are equal, so it should work ok